# Serialize Hash Table of StreamReaders

Tags: c#, serialization, stream, hashtable, filestream

Is it possible to serialize a hash table which has strings as keys and StreamReaders as values in c sharp? I want to read a bunch of files into an hash table and store the hash table in a binary file (and do this quite a few times). If so, how could I do this? I recall trying this some time back but the StreamReader or FileReader object I used was not serializable and it didn't work. Which object should I use? Or is this not possible?

If this is not possible, which would be the best way to store the files in the hash table? Think: 300 mb worth of text per file (but more realistically like 10 mb per file and about 10 of them). String? StringBuilder object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Stream is just an abstraction of reading bytes from somewhere. If you want to store multiple files in one, you need to *actually read* the streams into `byte` arrays and serialize those.

If it's text files only, you can read them using `File.ReadAllText` and store the strings in a `Dictionary<whatever, string>`. Please don't use `HashTable`, it's horribly outdated by about half a decade.

Comment: Yes, this is the case, but the text files can be huge, like 300 mb. Does putting that in a string cause problems? Like out of memory errors, etc? Thanks!

Comment: As long as you have 300mb RAM, it's fine. If the files get larger, you can read them byte-by-byte and serialize them in parts.

Comment: Ok! Thanks, that would be the worst case scenario! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do the contents of the files change? If not you could store just the file names.